# using the * selector in css, but exclude h1?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a jquery plugin, that annoyingly has this at the top of its stylesheet.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

It's causing my h1 to behave differently on this page. Is there a way to exclude certain selectors from this? Otherwise I guess I have to work out what it's applying to and list everything rather than *?

Comment: What weird behaviours are you getting? Those properties shouldn't change your h1 that much.

Comment: You could always just set these back for your h1.  It's only 3 rules.

Comment: what James said. You're drowning in a glass of water. Or simply remove that declaration from CSS if it annoys you that much

Comment: You should avoid using a `*` selection at all. The performance will not drop much in modern browsers, however it's better to rather style `html > body` and profit from the inheritance of the style options in the child elements

Comment: Not immediately practical, but I think the eventual answer would be to deploy the plugin as a Web Component.

Comment: @jerrylow it was just padding changing etc nothing major, just wanted to exclude it with ease, rather than create a class. It's annoying that some developer included this selector in their code in the first place.

Comment: @fabio tried removing it, the whole thing f'd up. I don't have the time to work out right now where it is applying to. I'm doing coursework and have a write up to follow, but will look at this in the future.

Comment: @GraemeWilkinson: this plugin is trying to take over your website. Get rid of it.

Comment: @NateWhittaker WebComponents are the shiznit, I can't wait to use them, 10 years from now ;)

Comment: As @SalmanA, I would at least open an issue on the plugin creator's github. As I told Juan, the 3rd party plugin creator did wrong by including that slow, generic selector instead of plugin-specific classes.

Comment: box-sizing border box makes life easier because the math is easier. Your h1 should not be messed up if you just adjust the math to include borders and padding. A 200px box with 2px padding is 196px sq with the conent-box sizing -- but with border-box it is 200px.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, quick answer is replace `*` for `*:not(h1)`.

This looks like a simple attempt of a normalize. You could remove it and fix whatever is wrong on plugin's elements or simply fix your `h1` to have the margin/padding it was supposed to have.

Comment: Gotta love people who downvote but does not comment why. I like opinions. I like even more people copying my answer minutes after I posted lol.

Comment: Don't pay attention to haters, your answer is good, +1 for you

Comment: Your answer is correct, no one should be downvoting it. Although I would refrain from saying people "copied" your answer.

Comment: @Mike Well, I agree people might have the same idea I had. But if you think about SO as a knowledge base, adding the same selector that first answer posted and not adding anything extra to it is undesirable as adds nothing to the question itself. That's what I meant by copying. Sorry if looked otherwise.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL yes, I made a point to mention which options provide which functionality (modern browser compliant vs. all browser compliant)

Comment: This still won't remove the styles from h1 that were applied by `* {box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}` You can only use this if you don't include the `*{...}` See http://jsfiddle.net/1pkpv3xc/

Comment: Perhaps the idea is to replace `*` with `*:not(h1)`?

Comment: @SalmanA That is included by a third party plugin that the OP doesn't have control over?

Comment: @Mike Which looks good, +1. I would suggest to add the 'modern browser list', you can see here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 I won't add to my post as I didn't mentioned before and that would be copying yours :D

Comment: @RaphaelDDL go ahead and add it your answer, I can't 'own' knowledge, it's for everyone :)

Comment: @JuanMendes OP didn't mention anything about not having control over, therefore my answer to replace `*` for `*:not(h1)` is okay. But yes, if he was importing from somewhere else, he had to use `h1{}` on his own stylesheet. But again, we are not working with suppositions of what could or what couldn't, we work with what is written on the question.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL Yeah, but it's common knowledge that modifying third-party code is bad practice because it makes upgrades a pain in the a$$. I think that requires at least some acknowledgment of that problem in your answer like: "if you can and are willing to live with the pains of modifying the third party CSS"

Comment: @JuanMendes Agree. But the first thing I would do is rip off that selector, that is a pain in the a$$ for anyone not using border-box. The 3rd party plugin creator did wrong by including that slow, generic selector instead of plugin-specific classes. But oh well, I always use normalize so that selector wouldn't affect me other than slower css parsing :P

Comment: My only issue with this solution is limited selector support, which is mentioned above.

Comment: @raphaelDDL if I want to insert normalize then, should I insert the http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.1/normalize.css at the start of my head, or the end? Sorry about this question, but might be a better solution

Comment: @GraemeWilkinson Yep, that's the most used. The trend is always add `box-sizing: border-box` because is widely supported and helps alot with the calcs for widths/paddings, etc. But I suggest you testing your website after adding it, as old websites didn't used them and for example, a 200px div with 10px padding had to be declared 180px width (to sum to 200). Now width 200px IS 200px, you still will have 10px padding but not the content that will have only 180px. Here's a good article to explain in case you have any doubts how it works: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: @raphaelDDL thanks! Both the normalize.css fixed this and your `*:not(h1)`, both solutions worked independently. Correct answer vote more than deserved. :)

Answer (score 7):

I would simply suggest you to use selector just `h1` which will override the all selector(*):

```
h1{
  box-sizing:content-box;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

---

It's always better to use `* selector` for eg. as you may want to change `#somecontent h1` but not `h1` then just using `#somecontent h1{...}` would override the rule of `* selector` and even just `h1 tag` will be benefited from `* selector`.

---

A really nice idea would be to override `* selector` itself if you're not interested with the plugin css:

```
*{
  border-box: content-box;
  margin: 0; /*add your value as you wish*/
  padding: 0; /*add your value as you wish*/
}
```

And you may also update the h1:

```
h1{
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

But to consider this, you must make sure that your css file is at last line of the plugin css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugin.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" /> <!-- last in order--->
```

Comment: This CSS is the same as his, he wants the CSS to NOT affect the h1 elements.

Comment: @Mike The OP can just apply the correct rules to `h1`, no? @C-linknepal Your answer would be better if your rules weren't the same as the ones the OP doesn't want to apply

Comment: To be honest, this isn't really an answer, but a comment. Looks better now it has been edited, but still looking more like a comment than an answer

Comment: @Fabio The answer you upvoted doesn't work, this works. See my comment and http://jsfiddle.net/1pkpv3xc/

Comment: @C-linkNepal Consider editing your comment that says RaphaelIDDL's answer works, it wonly works if you can edit the CSS that comes from the third party plugin. Modifying third-party code is not very good practice

Answer (score 1):

```
*:not(h1)
{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: This still won't remove the styles from h1 that were applied by `*
{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}` You can only use this if you don't include the `*{...}`

Answer (score 0):

modern browser solution

```
*:not(h1)
{
/* css code */
}
```

cross-browser compliant solution

```
h1{
box-sizing:none;
margin:auto;
padding:auto;
}
```

EDIT: removed superfluous !important flags.

Comment: It shouldn't be required (or desired) to add `!important`.  H1 will win because of specificity. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: I don't know who voted you down since your answer is "essentially" correct, but it's enough to declare *{...} and then h1{...} without the !important declaration

Comment: The !important flag is superfluous, I agree.

Comment: It was probably downvoted (not by me) because `!important` is for those who don't understand CSS specifity and cop out 99% of the time. Avoid it like the plague

Comment: @JuanMendes the flag has been removed.

Comment: Although, I would say in this case, my answer with the !important flag would work whether the user might have forgotten or missed another h1 css declaration.

Comment: @Mike That's why I'm saying it's a cop out, you should understand your CSS, rather than add `!important` because the user may have "forgotten???" another h1

Comment: @JuanMendes while I agree, the concept here is that we're trying to help 'Graeme Wilkinson'

Comment: It's a good idea to never use !important flags in answers unless you can explain why they are being used. That sort of thing tends to prompt knee-jerk reactions from some people.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer but I would suggest instead using inherit for box-sizing.  You can then easily reset an entire section if needed.  You end up with less code utilizing box-sizing: border-box; in this way.  Resetting your H1 is obvious.  Just reference it explicitly to bypass your universal selector.

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

**With this HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
<h1>Some Heading</h1>
</div>
```

**Reset it with this CSS:**

```
.content { box-sizing: content-box; }
```

Comment: Because people are using math like content-box but it's much easier to use box-sizing:border-box

Comment: @C-linkNepal I am simply offering an alternate solution to having to reset the box-sizing property, something that has become quite common in today's methods.

Resetting any margins or paddings is obvious, simply specify the H1 you want to reset explicitly...  This isn't rocket science.

Comment: This is a pretty clever workaround against the `*` selector, although I imagine you wouldn't be resetting it for an element *and* all its descendants all the time (except in the case of the aforementioned plugin), but that depends on the layout.